# Questions about implicit waits in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm reading the docs on Implicit Waiting with Webdriver but I'm not sure I totally understand.

As I understand it,

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This will put in place a timeout of 10 seconds whenever looking up any element.

What, exactly, does this do?

- Does it mean that when looking up any element, I will wait 10 seconds **every time**, even if the element is present? Or, when looking up any element, will the driver give the browser a 10-second grace period to load the element before deciding the element missing?
- Since this is applied to every element, am I correct in supposing that this is just executed only once for each instance of Webdriver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will look for the element up to 10 seconds, trying to locate it every 500 milliseconds (default timeout).

From the [docs](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

> Specifies the amount of time the driver should wait when searching for
> an element if it is not immediately present.
>
> When searching for a
> single element, the driver should poll the page until the element has
> been found, or this timeout expires before throwing a
> NoSuchElementException. When searching for multiple elements, the
> driver should poll the page until at least one element has been found
> or this timeout has expired.

The locating algorithm is described in [W3C specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-retrieval)

> The Find Element, Find Elements, Find Element From Element, and Find
> Elements From Element commands allow lookup of individual elements and
> collections of elements. Element retrieval searches are performed
> using pre-order traversal of the document’s nodes that match the
> provided selector’s expression. Elements are serialized and returned
> as web elements.
>
> When required to find with arguments start node, using and value, a
> remote end must run the following steps:
>
> 1. Let end time be the current time plus the session implicit wait
>    timeout.
> 2. Let location strategy be equal to using.
> 3. Let selector be equal to value.
> 4. Let elements returned be the result of trying to call the relevant
>    element location strategy with arguments start node, and selector.
> 5. If a DOMException, SyntaxError, XPathException, or other error occurs
>    during the execution of the element location strategy, return error
>    invalid selector.
> 6. If elements returned is empty and the current time
>    is less than end time return to step 4. Otherwise, continue to the
>    next step.
> 7. Let result be an empty JSON List.
> 8. For each element in elements returned, append the serialization of
>    element to result.
> 9. Return success with data result.

`implicitlyWait` is defined once for the `WebDriver` and last its lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

Defines a wait time globally in your project. Your telling your driver to wait for n number of seconds before selenium throws an exception. If element is found earlier then the n number of seconds you mentioned, webdriver will click it once its available and dont wait for the maximum n number of seconds. It does have to wait before it throws an exception.